# Marquee Animation UIimageView blur

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

[image]
[image]In my app images are in Marquee effect (HTML) . so i set the x point of image by using `NSTimer` but it implemented successfully but the image show some blur. how i remove this blur effect ?

```
int x=0;
ImgArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyframe1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyframe2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyframe3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyframe4.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"keyframe5.png"],nil];

imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 1024, 768)];`
imgView.image=[ImgArray objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.08 target:self selector:@selector(showMarquee) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

in showMarquee method change the value of x

Comment: Use UIView Animation instead of NStimer.

Comment: Check the resolution of image.

Comment: Not sure about others but I don't know what "Marquee effect" is. Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code for marquee effect.

declare **CAShapeLayer** object

```
CAShapeLayer *_marque;
```

Use the below methods:

```
-(void)setMarquee   {

    if (!_marque) {
        _marque = [CAShapeLayer layer] ;
        _marque.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        _marque.strokeColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
        _marque.lineWidth = 1.0f;
        _marque.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
        _marque.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];
        _marque.bounds = CGRectMake(self.imgView.frame.origin.x, self.imgView.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
        _marque.position = CGPointMake(self.imgView.frame.origin.x + self.imgView.frame.origin.x, self.imgView.frame.origin.y + self.imgView.frame.origin.y);
    }
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_marque];
}

-(void)showOverlayWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

        if (![_marque actionForKey:@"linePhase"]) {
            CABasicAnimation *dashAnimation;
            dashAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"lineDashPhase"];
            [dashAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
            [dashAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.0f]];
            [dashAnimation setDuration:0.5f];
            [dashAnimation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
            [_marque addAnimation:dashAnimation forKey:@"linePhase"];
        }

        _marque.bounds = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
        _marque.position = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + self.imgView.frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y + self.imgView.frame.origin.y);

        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, frame);
        [_marque setPath:path];
        CGPathRelease(path);

        _marque.hidden = NO;


}
```

Now call the methods

```
[self setMarquee];
[self showOverlayWithFrame:self.imgView.frame];
```

Just refer this project

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kaslideshow

Comment: Thanks ..manujmv. its show line in marquee animation but i needs images in left to right marquee animation