# How to create Marquee IOS Clickable

Tags: ios, marquee

Can you help me in how we can create a marquee for news , but I need that every new be clickable to show the detail page of the selected new.

I know we have many of examples considering marquee but no one was clickable for every item in the marquee.

Please help me

Comment: add UITapGestureRecognizer to your marquee "scrollView" to receive notifications

Comment: the problem is that only take in NSString so i cant specify the selected new

Comment: do you have already not clickable marquee UI?

Comment: yes but it take a NSString not an array that the problem

Comment: no, set NSString to marquee that's correct, but just memorize index of current (scrolling right now) news

Comment: may be it is usefull for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996819/marquee-animation-uiimageview-blur

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like this:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/marqueelabel

I'm assuming you should have `NSArray` of news. Put first news into marquee label as a text and start animating it. 
You may be notified when marquee view reaches end scrolling (animating) then, put second news.

That's how you know which news user's currently viewing.

To be able to click on marquee and get notification:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userDidTapOnNews:)];
    [marquee addGestureRecognizer: tap];

-(void)userDidTapOnNews:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // Marquee tapped, your turn ...
    // Use gestureRecognizer parameter if you need the view tapped
    Marquee *marque = gestureRecognizer.View;
    ...
    // Get news from your news `NSArray`

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: sorry but i didnt get you\